# Displaying Mean and Covariance in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I would like to display a set of observations along with their mean and covariance in gnuplot. Does anyone know how I might do something like this? Is there another program that would do this well? Would a program like Octave be able to do this? I see methods for getting statistics but I haven't found anything about displaying those stats.

To clarify, I want to display the data points (2d or 3d), show their mean plotted in the dataset, and show an ellipse representing the covariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Octave.

```
## create 2x1000 matrix of random data with normal distribution
data = randn (1000, 2);

## plot data (the o is for dots)
plot (data(:,1), data(:,2), "o");

## get mean from each
mu   = mean (data);

## calculate covariance matrix
R    = cov (data);

## calculate the ellipse points
A     = chol (R, "lower");
theta = linspace (0, 2*pi, 1000);
x     = mu' + 2.5 .* A * [cos(theta); sin(theta)];

## plot the ellipse
hold on;
plot(x(1,:), x(2,:), "r", "LineWidth", 2);
```

Comment: `theta=linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors about in octave 4.0.2 and changed the "x = " line in carandraug's answer to this:

```
x     = mu' + 2.5 .* A * [cos(theta); sin(theta)];
```